# javascript is not loading on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, opentok, tokbox

I have an app that works fine on local but when i deploy to heroku javascript not loading properly.i have seen many problems related to this on stackoverflow.but didnt work.

file that contain javascript

```
<div id="myPublisherDiv"></div>
<div id="subscribersDiv"></div>
<script src="http://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
alert("helloworld")
var apiKey = XXXXXX;//my apikey
var sessionId ="<%=@sessionId%>" ;
var token = "<%=@opentok_token%>";
var session;
OT.setLogLevel(OT.DEBUG);

session = OT.initSession(apiKey,sessionId);
var subscriberOptions = {
insertMode: 'append',
width: 340,
height: 260,
align: 'center'
};
session.on
({
    streamCreated: function(event)
    {
        session.subscribe(event.stream,'subscribersDiv',{insertMode: 'append',width:340,height:260});
    }
});

session.connect(token,function(error){
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    else{
        session.publish('myPublisherDiv',{width: 300,height: 220});
    }
}); 
</script>
```

nothing executed except alert function added above.

in **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'opentok'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.2.1"
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
 gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
 gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
 gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

i added in **production.rb**

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

and onething i have to say is i developed same app with other specifications without using bootstrap.it worked fine on heroku. but in this app i used bootstrap i guess this may be the issue.please help me.

**updated**
in browser console it shows

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting is quite self explanatory.

Your web app is configured to use **HTTPS** but it has dependencies on **HTTP**.

Changing

```
<script src="http://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

will fix your problem.

Comment: True, even docs says it should be `<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js"></script>` https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/

Comment: @vjnan369 However, you might need to use http while testing on localhost, cause you are not loading the app over https on local machine I assume.